# How to show ComboBox's SelectedValue if ComboBox is binded to a DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that is binded to a `DataSet`. I wanted to show the selected value whenever the `ComboBox` has a change in selection. I have the following code:

```
private void devCb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dv = new DataView(
        dt,
        "Device_ID = " + devCb1.SelectedIndex,
        "Data_ID ASC",
        DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

    dataDg1.ItemsSource = dv;
    devCb1.DisplayMemberPath = "Content";
    MessageBox.Show(devCb1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

But it only gives me

**System.Data.DataRowView**

I have already set the `DisplayMemberPath`, but it still not showing me the selected item's content. What is wrong?

[EDITED]
I also tries the following

```
devCb1.SelectedValuePath = "Content";
MessageBox.Show(devCb1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

But it also still gives me

**System.Data.DataRowView**

Doesn't work either..

Comment: Who the heck de-vote me at least leave a comment why you do so. I have searched around SO and google with no answer to this one.

Comment: I know it's bit long after the question was made, but I guess it's now possible to achieve the things you wanted in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataRowView` has no content [from what i can see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx). Your `SelectedValuePath` should point to `Row` i think (or if the current path correctly points to the `Content` of the `ComboBoxItem` you just need to cast at that point), and you'd still need to cast the `SelectedValue` being a row, to that class and from there you can get some of its content.

Set breakpoints, use the debugger, look at the data in your objects.

Comment: thanks but how can I point to Row? I tried devCb1.SelectedValuePath = "Row"  or MessageBox.Show((devCb1.SelectedValue as RowView).ToString()); but either one just throw me exception..

Comment: Updated my question since your content may the content of a ComboBoxItem you might need to retain the path and cast the selected value to DataRowView, and don't just call ToString on everything, you should pretty much never use that method, look at the data in the debugger and get the fields/properties you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try SelectedValuePath to access the data you want to view

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to access the data within DataRowView at least now (2 years after the question was made), by simply casting the **SelectedValue** to **System.Data.DataRowView** and accessing property **Row["colName"]** like this:

```
((System.Data.DataRowView)ComboBoxName.SelectedValue).Row["colName"];
```